# PHP - Echo <br>

Tags: php

I want my page to display `<br>Hello!`. But if I use

```
echo "<br>Hello!";
```

Then the `<br>` string is not displayed, but a newline is displayed instead. How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: Well that is what HTML does

Comment: @user557846 Well, PHP is not HTML and the documentation of "echo" doesn't mention it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use entities"

```
echo "&lt;br>Hello!";
```

OR `<xmp>` tag in HTML:

```
echo '<xmp><br>hello</xmp>'
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because you are using HTML, not replacing the symbols for text:

```
<?php
    echo "&lt;br&gt;Hello!";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo htmlspecialchars("<br>Hello!");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [HTML Entities](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) to represent `<` and `>`, so the browser understands it is supposed to render those characters, instead of interpreting them as an HTML tag. They are codes enclosed by `&` and `;` (see the link for examples).

In your case, the text **"<br>"** would be represented by `&lt;br;&gt`, where:

- `<` is represented by `&lt;`, which stands for **L**ower **T**han
- `>` is represented by `&gt;`, which stands for **G**reater **T**han

So you could go with

```php
echo htmlentities ("&lt;br;&gtHello!");
```

Fortunately, you don't have to memorise all codes. The PHP function [htmlentities](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) does the conversion for you:

```php
echo htmlentities ("<br>Hello!");
```